# Adjusting Homestead Settings for Two Separate Projects and VMs

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

This is a question related to setting up Homestead for my two Laravel projects.

I currently have a Laravel project under this file directory `Code/laravel`. Within `/laravel/` is where my first project's file resides (so my `app` folders.. `storage` folders.. et cetera).

My `Homestead.yaml` file is currently set up in this way:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"                                                       
memory: 2048                                                              
cpus: 1                                                                   
provider: virtualbox                                                      

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub                                              

keys:                                                                     
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa                                                       

folders:                                                                  
    - map: ~/Code                                                         
      to: /home/vagrant/Code                                              

sites:                                                                    
    - map: localhost                                                      
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

So when I run `vagrant up`, my host file which mapped that IP address to the URL `app.dev` would show my `Code/laravel/public` folder's pages.

However, I am currently in the process of setting up a NEW project.

This new project goes under `Code/schedulizer` (where `schedulizer` is the name of the new project).

How would I change my Homestead settings to add the second project?

***tl;dr:*** So to summarize, I have two SEPARATE projects under `/Code/`. My current Homestead settings is only configured for the project under `Code/laravel` and not `Code/schedulizer`. I want to have a VM for each project. What should I change my `Homestead.yaml` settings to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"                                                       
memory: 2048                                                              
cpus: 1                                                                   
provider: virtualbox                                                      

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub                                              

keys:                                                                     
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa                                                       

folders:                                                                  
    - map: ~/Code   // This is all your projects folder                                                       
      to: /home/vagrant/Code   // Will be placed here on homestead                                           

sites:                                                                    
    - map: laravel.app   // Laravel project domain                                                   
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public   // Path to your public folder for laravel project
    - map: schedulizer.app   // Schedulizer project domain                                                   
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/schedulizer/public   // Path to your public folder for schedulizer project
```

After Homestead.yaml configuration need to run `vagrant reload --provision`

You cant find more detailed info [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-laravel-homestead).

Comment: Thank you Viktor! One more question - what is the IP for the `laravel.app` and `schedulizer.app`? When I go to `192.168.10.10` it simply goes to the `laravel.app` location.

Comment: Nevermind. Got it. I just needed to update my hostfile to attribute that IP above to the two `map` values and it automagically works. Amazing how it knows that even if they share the same IP, when I use a different URL I assigned, it goes to the right site. Homestead is awesome.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck and enjoy Laravel.